# Using index sorting by default in _search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using ElasticSearch 7.6 and the Index Sorting feature which was introduced in 6.0.
What i am looking to do is to do a `GET /myindice/_search` **without specifying sort** and get documents based on Index sorting settings I have specified for my index and NOT insertion order.

My index as per the doc :

```
PUT twitter
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "sort.field" : "date", 
            "sort.order" : "desc" 
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT twitter/_doc/a
{
  "date": "2015-01-01"
}
PUT twitter/_doc/b
{
  "date": "2016-01-01"
}
PUT twitter/_doc/c
{
  "date": "2017-01-01"
}
```

My initial thought is that

```
GET twitter/_search
```

Should return doc C, B and A.
I get the following :

```
    {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "twitter",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2015-01-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "b",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2016-01-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "twitter",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2017-01-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As the documentation isn't clear at this particular subject and that all query are using sort :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/index-modules-index-sorting.html

Am I required to specify the sort order in the GET query (hence repeating the sort specified as the Index Sorting) ?

Thanks in advance for any diligent soul that could help me,